# save CMTime in core data + Xcode8 + swift3

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, cmtime, transformable

I declared two attributes (`currentTime` and `fullTime`) as `Transformable` in data model as shown below.

[image]

How to save data in this attribute? Do I need to convert to `NSData` first? or any other way?

Comment: `Transformable` attributes can have any object type (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSData`, etc). However, what's wrong with using primitive (`float`) type, or Decimal (`NSDecimalNumber`)?

Answer (score 1):

Transformable need to be convertible to `NSData`. When you're using a type that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, that happens automatically. When you're not (as with `CMTime`), you can't use a transformable unless you create your own custom transformer by subclassing `NSValueTransformer`.

You may find it easier to simply save the `CMTime` properties in Core Data and reconstruct the `CMTime` from those. The properties are all numeric types that Core Data knows how to handle.